# window.resize event firing in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, resize, jquery-events

As you are aware, in Internet Explorer, **the window.resize event is fired when any element on the page is resized.** It does not matter whether the page element is resized through assigning/changing its height or style attribute, by simply adding a child element to it, or whatever -- even though the element resizing does not affect the dimensions of the viewport itself.

In my application, this is causing a nasty recursion, since in my window.resize handler I am resizing some <li> elements, which in turn re-fires window.resize, etc. Again, this is only a problem in IE.

Is there any way to **prevent window.resize from firing in IE in response to elements on the page being resized?**

I should also mention that I'm using jQuery.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. I'm not familiar with JQuery but it should be possible to stop the event if its source element is not the window itself. I'm sure somebody will come up with a coded solution.

Comment: What version of IE is this in and can you provide some code that actually shows resizing an element fires window.resize?

Comment: Not should about other versions, but it happens in IE 8

Comment: i cannot thank you enough for this question. i kept pulling my hair off: "WHY IS MY PAGE SO SLOW?" turns out ie8 kept firing window.resize on every frame and then my resize handler would have to reposition everything over and over again

Comment: Thanks for this. Can confirm it's a problem on IE9 as well.

Comment: "as you are aware". if I was, I wouldn't be here. nor would I have spent the past 3 hours trying to work out why an app was behaving very differently in ie9 compared to any other browser, including ie8,10 and 11! thx for asking the question anyway! :) +1

Answer (score 60):

I just discovered another problem which might help you.

I am using jQuery and I have window.resize event to call a function which will re-position the div appended to the body.

Now when I set the LEFT css property of that appended div, the window.resize event get trigger for NO GOOD REASON.

It results in an infinite loop, triggering the window.resize again and again.

## The code without fix:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var onResize = function(){
        //The method which alter some css properties triggers 
        //window.resize again and it ends in an infinite loop
        someMethod();
    }
    window.clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
    resizeTimeout = window.setTimeout(onResize, 10);
});
```

## Solution:

```
var winWidth = $(window).width(),
    winHeight = $(window).height();

$(window).resize(function(){
    var onResize = function(){
        //The method which alter some css properties triggers 
        //window.resize again and it ends in an infinite loop
        someMethod();
    }

    //New height and width
    var winNewWidth = $(window).width(),
        winNewHeight = $(window).height();

    // compare the new height and width with old one
    if(winWidth!=winNewWidth || winHeight!=winNewHeight){
        window.clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
        resizeTimeout = window.setTimeout(onResize, 10);
    }
    //Update the width and height
    winWidth = winNewWidth;
    winHeight = winNewHeight;
});
```

So basically it will check if the height or width is changed (which will happen ONLY when you actually resize with window).

Comment: Aamir, looks like that do the trick. Let me try it and I'll come back and let you know how it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the idea to check and see if the window's width/height have changed to see if the actually window resized or not!

Comment: is onResize global on purpose or did you forget the var?

Comment: Great solution - had the same infinite loop situation which this fix remedied.

Comment: While it remains a good idea to check if the width or height has changed, this doesn't solve the scenario in which the `resize` handler is continuously triggered even though the width and height remains the same. In my case it was the `document` object causing the handler to trigger and resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: I found that on a certain UI change I was getting a false resize event firing twice -- the window was shrinking in width by 17px and then growing the 17px back. I wound up doing some math and setting a tolerance of 20px before trusting it is a real resize. I supposed maybe this is the scroll bar appearance -- even though there is no perceptible change on the UI as it probably happens too fast.

Answer (score 25):

this made sense to me and seems to work in IE7 and above:

```
    //variables to confirm window height and width
    var lastWindowHeight = $(window).height();
    var lastWindowWidth = $(window).width();

    $(window).resize(function() {

        //confirm window was actually resized
        if($(window).height()!=lastWindowHeight || $(window).width()!=lastWindowWidth){

            //set this windows size
            lastWindowHeight = $(window).height();
            lastWindowWidth = $(window).width();

            //call my function
            myfunction();


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 19):

Bind your resize listener with `.one()` so that it unbinds itself after firing. Then you can do anything you want, so long as at the end you rebind the resize listener. I found the easiest way to do this is by putting the resize listener in an anonymous function like so:

```
var resizeListener = function(){
  $(window).one("resize",function(){ //unbinds itself every time it fires

    //resize things

    setTimeout(resizeListener,100); //rebinds itself after 100ms
  });
}
resizeListener();
```

You don't technically need the `setTimeout` wrapped around the `resizeListener()` but I'd threw it in there as a just-in-case and for some extra throttling.

Comment: Excellent solution. Remember that functions *are* full-fledged objects in JavaScript, so `resizeListener` can be passed directly to `setTimeout()` instead of using the string literal `"resizeListener();"`.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, @user113215. I updated the code based on your suggestion.

Comment: awesome approach without using any extra variables or if statements

Comment: @brentonstrine This solved my problem of `$(window).resize()` hanging on IE8. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by unbinding the resize function, rebuilding the page and then binding the resize function again:

```
function rebuild() {
   $(window).unbind('resize');
   /* do stuff here */
   $(window).bind('resize',rebuild);
}

$(window).bind('resize',rebuild);
```

EDIT

Bind and unbind don't go well with IE8. Though Microsoft even gave up on IE8 you might want to try this (untested!):

```
function rebuild(){
   if(!window.resizing) return false;
   window.resizing=true;
   /* do stuff here */
   window.resizing=false;
}

window.resizing=false;
document.body.onresize=rebuild;
```

Comment: This seemed like the most elegant solution, but doesn't seem to actually work for me unfortunately. I'm testing in IE 8 on Windows XP and Chrome 36 on OS X 10.9.

Comment: Yeah, the jQuery bind and unbind don't go together well with IE8. I doubt they (jQuery) will fix it since even Microsoft doesn't support IE8/XP anymore since April 8, 2014...

Comment: A workaround could be to set a global parameter in the beginning of function rebuild that you check for before resizing:

function rebuild(){ 
  if(window.resizing) return false; 
  window.resizing=true;

  /* do stuff here */ 
  
  window.resizing=false;); => edited the answer for readability

Answer (score 4):

@AamirAfridi.com's answer solved my problem.

It's a good idea to write a common function to solve such stuff:

```js
function onWindowResize(callback) {
    var width = $(window).width(),
        height = $(window).height();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var newWidth = $(window).width(),
            newHeight = $(window).height();

        if (newWidth !== width || newHeight !== height) {
            width = newWidth;
            height = newHeight;
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Use it like this, and you don't have to worry about the different behavior in IE any more:

```js
onWindowResize(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Better to check use callback with setTimeout just to make sure user has finished resizing the window

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem today and decided to put the following at the top of my global included javascript file:

```
var savedHeight = 0;
var savedWidth = 0;
Event.observe(window, 'resize', function (e) {
    if (window.innerHeight == savedHeight && 
        window.innerWidth == savedWidth) { e.stop(); }
    savedHeight = window.innerHeight;
    savedWidth = window.innerWidth;
});
```

That requires Prototype, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

A mix of the `unbind` / `bind` method with a delayed call.
It works in Internet Explorer 8 and below, preventing evil loop and hangs on versions 6 and 7.

```js
function resizeViewport()
{
    // Unbind and rebind only for IE < 9
    var isOldIE = document.all && !document.getElementsByClassName;

    if( isOldIE )
        $(window).unbind( 'resize', resizeViewport );

    // ...

    if( isOldIE )
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(window).resize( resizeViewport );
        }, 100);
    }
}

$(window).resize( resizeViewport );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

**Constructor:**

```
this.clientWidth = null;
this.clientHeight = null;
```

**Some function:**

```
var clientWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth; 
var clientHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
if (clientWidth != this.clientWidth || clientHeight != this.clientHeight ) {
    this.clientWidth = clientWidth;
    this.clientHeight = clientHeight;

    ... YOUR CODE ...
}
```

For Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari:

```
window.innerHeight - the inner height of the browser window
window.innerWidth - the inner width of the browser window
```

For Internet Explorer 8, 7, 6, 5:

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight
document.documentElement.clientWidth
    or
document.body.clientHeight
document.body.clientWidth
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($){
     //if ie8 -> return;
     var lastHeight = 0;
     var lastWidth = 0;
     $(window).resize(function(event){
         if (window.innerHeight == lastHeight && window.innerWidth == lastWidth)
             { event.stopImmediatePropagation(); }
         lastHeight = window.innerHeight;
         lastHeight = window.innerWidth;
     });
})();
```

does the trick for me...

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>



var cont = 0;
var tmRsize = 100;
var lastWindowWidth = $(window).width();
var lastWindowHeight = $(window).height();

/*****redimensionamiento**********/
$(window).resize(function()
{
    if($(window).width() != lastWindowWidth || $(window).height() != lastWindowHeight)
    {
        clearTimeout(this.id);
        this.tiempo = tmRsize;
        this.id = setTimeout(doResize, this.tiempo);
    }
});

function doResize()
{
    lastWindowWidth = $(window).width();
    lastWindowHeight = $(window).height();

    $('#destino_1').html(cont++);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i deal with finding out if the resize event was fired by an element or by really resizing the window:

If the event's target.nodeType doesn't exist, it is most likely the window, as any other element on the page would have a nodeType.

So here's the pseudo-code (using jQuery) with the added check:

```
$(window).resize(function(event){
    if ( $(event.target.nodeType).length == 0 ){
        // Anything here is run when the window was resized
        // not executed when an element triggered the resize
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't get the resize event to fire when an element resized (only tried in IE8 though).

However what is the `target` on the event object when you're experiencing this issue, could you do:

```
$(window).resize(function(e) {
    if( e.target != window ) return;
    // your stuff here
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because when an element triggers the window.resize, the target on the window.resize is always window. This is why I starting to suspect that it actually can't be done...

Answer (score -1):

My patch:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onresize = null;       // patch to prevent infinite loop in IE6 and IE7
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I would never recommend to mess with windows objects like this way.

Answer (score -2):

It is up to the how contents are on the resize event.

I figured out the above solves only when a page consists of static contents, not dynamically rendered ones.
In the dynamic case where the existing contents will be re-rendered by some trigger event like a contents reload function, we need to use $(document).width() or $(document).height() instead.

This is because of scroll bar of the window.
If a page has the scroll bar and the main contents will be re-rendered by clicking a button “Reload”, the scroll bar disappears on the event.
In that case, $(window).width() or $(window).height() is changed by the contents rendering, not by the actual window resizing.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Answer (score -3):

```
$(window).resize(function(event)
{
    if (typeof event.target.tagName == 'undefined')
    {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: What about this answer adds/improves the other highly rated answers?  A code-only answer is not good.  Provide explanation.