# Alternatives to jQuery endless scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scroll

Are there any alternatives to the jQuery endless scrolling plugin?

http://www.beyondcoding.com/2009/01/15/release-jquery-plugin-endless-scroll/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example the [infinite scroll plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/)

Comment: According to Paul Irish's GitHub page it is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 61):

This should do the same trick without plugin

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100) {
      //Add something at the end of the page
   }
});
```

### EDIT *Jan 15, 2014*

According to @pere's comment, **it's better to use the code below to avoid excessive amount of event firing**.

Inspired from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13298018/153723

```
var scrollListener = function () {
    $(window).one("scroll", function () { //unbinds itself every time it fires
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100) {
            //Add something at the end of the page
        }
        setTimeout(scrollListener, 200); //rebinds itself after 200ms
    });
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    scrollListener();
});
```

Comment: I would like to link a [blog post of jQuery's author John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/) about best practices. He recommends not doing 'too much' inside the window scroll event (like manipulating the DOM, or doing an AJAX call) as that event **will fire multiple times** when the user scrolls the page.

Comment: I think your edited version loses important scroll events.  If I quickly scroll to the end of a page, it will handle the first event (maybe just a few pixels) and disable the listener.  By the time the listener is reenabled, I could already have hit the end of the page.

Proposed fix: In scrollListener, compare scrollTop to the previous value, and react immediately if there's been further scrolling.

Answer (score 7):

Combining Ergec's answer and Pere's comment:

```
function watchScrollPosition(callback, distance, interval) {
    var $window = $(window),
        $document = $(document);

    var checkScrollPosition = function() {
        var top = $document.height() - $window.height() - distance;

        if ($window.scrollTop() >= top) {
            callback();
        }
    };

    setInterval(checkScrollPosition, interval);
}
```

`distance` is the number of pixels from the bottom of the screen when the callback will fire.

`interval` is how often the check will run (in milliseconds; 250-1000 is reasonable).

Comment: I like your idea but its consuming more from the browser then the Ergec idea. Its running even that the user is not scrolling and Ergec solution is not running at this situation. I think the best solution is to use Ergec solution and add a unbind event to the window scroll in case that the user scroll to the end of the page.

Comment: @RoyShoa I've edited my answer. Now it's most efficient.

Comment: Grate, +1 one me to on my idia :)

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find one that did exactly what I wanted so I built one from scratch.  It has a pause feature so it doesn't keep loading endlessly as you scroll.  Sometimes somebody might want to see the page footer.  It simply appends a "Show More" button to continue appending.  I also incorporated localStorage so when a user clicks away they won't lose their place in the results.

http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/9445/

It also has a callback function that can be called to manipulate the newly appended results.

Answer (score 1):

This should take care of a bug where the user reaches the bottom of the page before the event fires.  I was seeing this in my project you should check prior to initializing the event if you're already at the bottom of the page.

```
var scrollListener = function () {
    executeScrollIfinBounds();
    $(window).one("scroll", function () { //unbinds itself every time it fires
       executeScrollIfinBounds();
        setTimeout(scrollListener, 200); //rebinds itself after 200ms
    });
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    scrollListener();
});

function executeScrollIfinBounds()
{
     if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100) {
            //Add something at the end of the page
        }
}
```