# Infinite Scrolling Using Ajax and probably jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are just too many options to choose for implementing infinite scroll of search results using ajax.

Like [this one](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Infinite-Ajax-Scroll-Plugin-ias-js.html), but the size is like 44k, which i suppose is too high.

Is there any better ajax-infinite scroll api available?

Alternatively, should I build this on my own? It seems like reinventing the wheel.

Also, skelton of all search results is the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841585/alternatives-to-jquery-endless-scrolling/4842226#4842226

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Look here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-infinite-scrolling-web-gallery--net-10653
Or look here: http://sandmoose.com/post/24430017265/infinite-scrolling-demo-without-plugins

There are plenty of alternatives. If you're looking for smaller sizes then probably pure javasript implementation is the way to go. For instance this may be the solution: https://github.com/alexblack/infinite-scroll