# IE and JavaScript: window reload on resize

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Reasoning for Script:
Reloads various CSS scripts based on browser detected width and height. Window reload in needed to reload the other JavaScript as browser is resizing.

Problems Occurred:
IE likes to loop continuously.

Compatibility with other scripts:
Chrome, FireFox, Safari work

Script used:

```
<body onResize="window.location.href = window.location.href;">
```

Someone please come up with a better solution or suggestion!! This has to work for Safari, IE, and FireFox.

Possibly else if logic based on what type of browser?

SOLUTIONS BELOW (JQUERY): [window.resize event firing in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852751/window-resize-event-firing-in-internet-explorer/1921259#1921259)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var winWidth = $(window).width(),
winHeight = $(window).height();

$(window).resize(function(){

onResize = function() {
//The method which sets the LEFT css property which triggers 
//window.resize again and it was a infinite loop
setWrapperPosition($mainWrapper.parent());
}

//New height and width
var winNewWidth = $(window).width(),
winNewHeight = $(window).height();

// compare the new height and width with old one
if(winWidth!=winNewWidth || winHeight!=winNewHeight)
{
window.clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
resizeTimeout = window.setTimeout(onResize, 10);
}
//Update the width and height
winWidth = winNewWidth;
winHeight = winNewHeight;
});
});
```

Comment: Flaw is the design loading css based on page size.

Comment: Google for "CSS media queries" ...

Comment: As an alternative, split up your CSS artificially and set a class on the `<body>` or `<html>` in the size change handler.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
window.location.reload()
```

to reload the page.

Also, I'm not sure if `onresize` is a widely-supported event.

Instead, I'd do it with a timer (source here http://jsfiddle.net/ACpTm/4/)

---

But I REALLY would not advise anyone to reload the page due to styling. It's a bad practice and the user dislikes it, especially if they have limited bandwidth.

Could you describe *why* you need to do this? We could provide a more versatile solution instead of this.

Comment: I'm not really allowed to go into detail, but I am working on a project where statistics and information is constantly being displayed on all various resolutions for employees. People will be up close or far away. I can't use CSS percentages because of the details in the display. People will be using different monitors at various distances.

Comment: That's what I mean. You can do just that in CSS without any sort of JS hacking. Can you provide an example page or something?

Comment: So you are talking about doing something like Joomla. I can't use 1-100%. Space is very very limited, and can not use that. I have to use JavaScript. If you could please provide an example I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You would be way better off if you didn't base your CSS on the browser size.

You could use Javascript/jQuery to resize things in the window onResize event, I had to do this once in the past and it worked ok.

Comment: Do you have a solution to the question though?  Also please provide your script example you mentioned with an explanation.

Comment: This question doesn't need a solution like the one you are asking for.  It's bad practice to reload the page like that.