# window.resize always triggers in IE without resize

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

***Old title:*** Included PHP doesn't work with JQuery and IE in a function as expected

I have these two function:

First:

```
/* dynamic menue */
$("#wrapper div").not(":first").hide();
$("#nav p").click(function () {  
$('#wrapper div').eq($(this).index()).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Second:

```
 var menue = function (menue) {
 if ($(window).width() < 680) {
    $("#nav").hide();
    $("#wrapper div").show();
 } else  {
    $("#nav").show();
    $("#wrapper div").not(":first").hide();
 }
};
$(document).ready(menue);
$(window).resize(menue);
```

<strike>​The first function works well and the second makes sure that all content is shown without the menue if the window size is beyond 680px otherwise it will show the normal state. Everything works fine in all browsers.</strike>

I made up a fiddle for visualisation: http://jsfiddle.net/TFeWY/

<strike>However this doesn't work in IE as expected with this setup: The div content is generated with php. In this state I only see the first div in IE and can't switch to the other but resize works well. However if I change the php content with html it all works properly again. More interesting: If I leave the php untouched an just remove the else statement it also works.</strike>

So far I couldn't figure out weather it's the php content (what I don't think) or the hide() command in context of the php content.

Is something wrong in the function for IE? (Tested in IE8)

**Edit:**

If I remove the $(window).resize(menue); it also works. So it must be something wrong with the function itself?

I found out that the window.resize function is always trigged in IE 8, that's the reason why I can't see the other divs.

How can I do something about that?

Comment: Also, why don't you just use css `@media-queries` and `respond.js` as polyfill for IE? Just a suggestion...

Comment: Yes that is what I always prefer. But since I use the function to switch between the content I found no way to switch bewteen the user generated divs (the number always vary) in css for doing this.

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of html even if it's supposed to be dynamic? It might help to see where the problem comes from

Comment: The html structure is the exact same I set up in the fiddle just with different names and some <p> tags inside the divs.

Comment: I just tried IE8 with that jsFiddle and I get the same behavior as in Firefox 10...

Comment: That's what I said. The fiddle works. But not in IE 8 when the div content is generated with php. But it does work with php when I remove the else statement, as mentioned in the question I want to know why this behavior exists.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the PHP code? Don't know...

Comment: The code works fine and is used in the page a couple of times without a problem running in IE 8. And as I said, it works even with PHP when I remove the else statement. So I guess it must be the function?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the function, except maybe that you're not using the functions' parameter anywhere `function (menue)` but I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: I already tried to split the function, separate ready and resize too but without no solution yet. This is pretty weird.

Comment: Why this `$(document).ready(menue);`? Try wrapping you `$(window).resize(menue);` in DOM ready too.

Comment: Tried that, nothing changed. I use ready on the elements to make sure that this state will be setup when I user opens the site on a mobile device and not only on resize.

Comment: Man, don't know what else to say. Hopefully you get other people to help.

Comment: Thanks for your effort anyways! I will try a bit more and hope that I find something out or someone knows something about this.

Comment: just a note, `$(window).width()` is not the "screen" width, but rather just the width of the viewable window inside the open browser

Comment: Yes, I actually mean the window width. I corrected it in my question for that's not misleading.

Comment: Ok, I totally rebuild the question for the reason that I found out that IE 8 always triggers the window.resize without a resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found an answer:

Actually here is a post to my question which describes what is happening here: [window.resize event firing in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852751/window-resize-event-firing-in-internet-explorer)

Check out this updated fiddle in IE 8. It doesn't work as I described cause the resize is triggered:

http://jsfiddle.net/TFeWY/1/

Now you could work with the given answer of the post mentioned above.

**Or here is a fix of a friend of mine which I use now:**

http://jsfiddle.net/TFeWY/2/

A very interesting solution I think.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps re-organize your code, with something like that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#wrapper div:gt(0)").hide();
    $("#nav p").live('click',function () {  
    $('#wrapper div').eq($(this).index()).show().siblings().hide();
    }); 
    menue();
    $(window).live('resize',function(){menue()});
});

function menue() {
 if ($(window).width() < 680) {
    $("#nav").hide();
    $("#wrapper div").show();
 } else  {
    $("#nav").show();
    $("#wrapper div:gt(0)").hide();
 }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with my question eather but of course it's correct, yes. But while I was trying your answer out I accidentally came to an answer which I just posted. Strange but working.

Comment: Did you tried :  $(window).live('resize',function(){menue()}); ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I tried a lot till I finally found out what the problem actually was as I describe in my answer.