# Remove window "resize" listener

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, resize, dom-events

This question relates closely to the stack overflow question "[window.resize event firing in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852751/window-resize-event-firing-in-internet-explorer)".

**The Issue:**
I am attempting to fix a resizing issue in Internet Explorer 8. Currently, the resize function gets called repeatedly causing IE to essentially lock up - the user can no longer use buttons that call Javascript actions.

**Previous Attempt(s):**

```
var resizeTimeout;
var resizeHandler = function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
    //$(window).unbind('resize', resizeHandler);
    //window.removeEventListener('resize');
    window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeHandler, false);
    scrollHandler();
    setTimeout("$(window).resize(resizeHandler);", 100);
    return true;
}
//$(window).resize(resizeHandler);
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler, false);
```

**Problems:** It appears that `window` cannot implement `addEventListener` or `removeEventListener` and unbinding jQuery doesn't stop IE from continuing to freak out. It works fine in all other browsers.

**Desired Behavior:** The goal here is really to get IE to stop repetitively executing code so other functions like `onclick` events work.

---

Does anyone know how I can remove the resize event after it's been added or simply make IE stop being retarded. (<-- Extra points if you can make IE not be retarded.)

---

**Resolution:** Inside of the `scrollHandler` function a variable was not declared using the `var` prefix. Adding var made all the evil fairies go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. What you should be doing is using that timeout to block the invocation of "scrollHandler()" until the window resizing activity has paused for a little while (like the 100ms delay you're using).

```
var resizeTimeout;
function resizeHandler() {
  cancelTimeout(resizeTimeout);
  resizeTimeout = setTimeout(scrollHandler, 100);
}
$(window).resize(resizeHandler);
```

Trying to do DOM updates (which I assume to be what goes on inside "scrollHandler") in a "resize" handler is really not a good idea in *any* browser.  By doing that, you won't need to get rid of the "resize" handler at all.

*edit* — OK now I see that that's effectively what you were trying to do.  I still think it's a lot simpler this way.

Comment: The application I'm working on, which I did not develop, is repositioning a pop-in window when the page moves. So something has to happen as a result of the resize. However, I added a counter that prints out how many times the resize event was being called and it was only getting called about 3 times. It turns out inside of the scrollHandler function was a variable being used without a "var" in front of it. Defining the variable "var obj" fixed the issue.