# Blocking access to certain function

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

On my page I have two buttons -

```
<input type="button" value="Fit Window" onclick="FitWindow()">
<input type="button" value="Actual Size" onclick="ActualSize()">

function FitWindow()
{
   $("body").css("zoom",iZoomValue*100+"%"); 
}
function ActualSize()
{
   $("body").css("zoom","1"); 
}
```

What happens is initially a big image is zoomed in (using CSS) to fit to window. If users wants to see the actual size, he can click on the actual size button. I am also catching the resize event so if user resizes the browser window, image will be zoomed in according to browser window height and width.

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
   FitWindow();
});
```

It works fine on other browsers, however, in IE when user clicks on button it somehow detects the resize event and jumps to `FitWindow()` function (i guess due to IE's behaviour while dealing with resize event). What I am looking for is whether its possible to detect the button event and avoiding the resize function to be called ?

Comment: `Actual Size` is not a valid identifier, as it contains a Space.

Comment: Can you please provide the code of `FitWindow()` and `Actual Size()`

Comment: I suggest putting an id on both buttons

Comment: @Lukx I have put the code of both the functions over there

Comment: Take a look [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852751/window-resize-event-firing-in-internet-explorer).  Maybe something there can assist someone in creating a solution.  It contains information on the IE Resize issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the resize event, look for `$("body").css("zoom") != 1`, e.g.:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
   if ($("body").css("zoom") != 1)
      FitWindow();
});
```