# IE Jquery glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

On my website i'm using a few custom built jquery plugins and a couple of external ones.

The problem i am having is occurring only in IE. On this page i have a KenBurns Jquery Slider and some jquery tabs. Both plugins work fine on Chrome / Firefox. However on IE when i toggle between the tabs (below the KenBurns Slider) the first tab remains open and does not hide. Also the Ken Burns Slider reloads or seems to reload itself.

Does anyone know why this is happening or would be willing to take a look?

Page: http://devsite80.clickdealer.co.uk/used-land-rover-range-rover-364746

My Tabs code:

```
(function($) {

jQuery(document).ready(function () {


// Generate Tabs
$(".tabContents").hide();
    $(".tabContents:first").show();

    $("#tabContaier ul li a").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#tabContaier ul li a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tabContents").hide();
        $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    });

// Fix Tabs for Mobile
$(window).resize(function(){
    console.log('resize called');
    var width = $(window).width();
    if(width <= 757){
           $('.tabContents').show();
     }
     else{
            $(".tabContents:first").show();
     }
})
.resize();//trigger the resize event on page load.

});

}(jQuery));
```

Here is a link to the other plugins i'm calling:
http://devsite80.clickdealer.co.uk/js/jquery.config.js

If you need any more info please let me know :-)

Thank you for your help guys!!

Comment: Shouldn't `.tabContents:first` be `.tabContents:first-child`?

Also I noticed this potential typo: `$("#tabContaier ul li a").removeClass("active");` should be tabContainer I think, but I'm assuming either it's consistent or a transcription error since you mention this works except in IE...

Answer (score 1):

You issue is you are binding to window.resize. In IE, **the window.resize event is fired when any element on the page is resized.**

The article hear discusses it more:
[window.resize event firing in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852751/window-resize-event-firing-in-internet-explorer)

I would not recommend to binding on resize. Instead of using hide and show I would move this functionality to you CSS and use jQuery to toggle your classes. This will also allow you to set CSS media queries to accomplish what you need:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 757px) {
    #YOUR CONDITIONAL CSS HERE
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with binding on resize events, when a css only approach is not appropriate. Then you can bind the resize event. Keep in mind that in some instances IE, and webkit browsers will keep firing the resize event in a loop. Thats when the link you provided is a great solution..

Answer (score 0):

I get a syntax error:

`'position().left' is null or not an object` on line 128, char 644 of jquery.themepunch.kenburn.min.js

Also, for whatever reason resize is getting called 4 times in IE before the error. You can hit F12 on IE to get to the developer tools, then go back to the page and refresh it to see errors. Click on the "Script" tab of course.

FYI, Refreshing the tools console just clears the cache but I don't think it'll reload the page, you actually have to reselect the IE window.

I should add that the images don't show as thumbnails for me, just as a vertical list of images. Lastly, I'm on IE8 (8.0.6001.18702IC) on WinXP.

Comment: If you can get an unminifed version of the JS and post it to JSFiddle or something that might help to diagnose your issue further. Also, if the plugin works with more up-to-date (or less up-to-date...) versions of jQuery, I might try that to see if it's a rare bug in jQuery or something... in Chrome I still get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` from jquery.min.js