# IE8, jQuery UI Tooltip closes immediately in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8

**The setup**

We have a jQuery UI tooltip that is displayed via a `mouseenter` event attached to the `<div class="fieldset">` (.fieldset) element inside the form element.  When the mouse leaves the div, the tooltip should disappear.

**The problem**

In IE8, and only IE8, the tooltip disappears immediately when you hover over the area of the `.fieldset` element.  IE8 behaves as if the child elements are not actually decedents of the parent element, or as if the tooltip is using the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events.  However, we are using the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events for this tooltip.

I have tried giving the `.fieldset` element a solid background.  I also tried a transparent image.  I've checked the `z-index` of the child elements to make sure there weren't different.  Nothing I do seems to work.

I need the tooltip to stay displayed while the mouse hovers over the `.fieldset` element and any of its children.

**Code**

HTML:

```
<form class="form centerBH" id="form" style="display: block; zoom: 1;">

    <div class="fieldset">

        <h2 class="legend">Autogenerated Image Links</h2>

        <div id="image" class="panebox" >
        <div class="ui-widget"> 
            <ul>

            </ul>
        </div>      
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.form {

    width: 50em;

    /* correct margin collapse in IE */
    overflow: auto;
}

/* ensure all form elements will fade in and out */
form * {

    filter: inherit;

}

.panebox {

    background-color: #F7F7F7;

    border-color: #B7B9BD;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;

    box-shadow:  0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.7), 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.1);

    margin: 7px;
    padding: 14px;

    position: relative;

    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JavaScript:

Again, I'm using jQuery UI tooltip, which automagically binds to any elements that have a title attribute defined.  However, I have tried explicitly attaching the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to the `.fieldset` div, to display and hide the tooltip, but I still get the same behavior.

Here is how I setup the tooltip:

```
this.fieldsetTooltip=this.$(".fieldset").tooltip({

            content: 'Click an image link to open that image.',
            disabled: true,
            items: ".fieldset",
            position: {
                my:"left+20 top+25", 
                at:"right top",
                collision: "none",
                using: function( position, feedback ) {

                    //console.log(feedback.target.width);

                    $( this ).css( position );

                    $( "<div>" )
                        .addClass( "arrow" )
                        .addClass( feedback.vertical )
                        .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
                        .appendTo( this );
                }

            }
        });
```

Here is how I manually open and close the tooltip:

```
this.$el.on("mouseenter",'.fieldset',function(e){

        console.log("Mouse entering .fieldset");
        _this.fieldsetTooltip.tooltip("open");


});


this.$el.on("mouseleave",'.fieldset',function(e){

        console.log("Mouse leaving .fieldset");
        _this.fieldsetTooltip.tooltip("close");


});
```

We also trigger a custom resize event when the window object triggers it's resize event.

```
// close tooltip when user resizes the window
this.listenTo(AppReg.events,"context:resized",function() {

        _this.fieldsetTooltip.tooltip("close");
});
```

**Update**
Based on the console log from the above events, the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events are firing as they should.  However, I think the jQuery UI tooltip is binding a different event to the element (maybe a 'mouseout'?), which is causing it to close automatically.

Anybody know how this can be stopped?

Comment: Do you nave a demo (including js)?

Comment: That would be very hard to do, since this is a very large single-page web app.  I've tried to narrow down the pieces above, however, let me see what I can do.

Comment: Yea, see if you can isolate subset that gives you the issue

Comment: It may be very large, but the problem you are having is very localized (and likely small). create a small example that recreates just this one problem.

Comment: Does the browser's default tooltip work?

Comment: @SalmanA  Yes, the normal tooltip appears once the jQuery UI disappears.

Comment: I' will try and create a small example, this is part of a large backbone.js app, with many different views/models, etc.  I will try to extrapolate this one form view and the jqueryUI tooltip.  I was hoping there was a known bug related to IE8 and the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events; maybe related to using a css filter to fade-in/out the elements...if nothing jumps out at anyone I will just create an example.  My luck would be the example will work and the complete app wont...

Comment: I would also suggest that you use the IE developer tools (press F12), refresh the DOM (click the _refresh_ button in the developer tools) and use the _Select element by click_ option. Try to hover over the element and see if it is highlighted on mouseover.

Comment: @SalmanA  All the elements are highlighted when inspecting. The child elements are not underneath any elements, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit to the problem is the way that IE8 handles the resize event.  I was attaching a resize event handler on the window object, using `$(window).resize()`.  For some reason, IE8  was firing the resize event whenever the tooltip was displayed.

I used the solution from this post: [window.resize event firing in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852751/window-resize-event-firing-in-internet-explorer)

Basically, you have to check to make sure the window's dimensions actually changed before firing the event.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit similar issue on Nokia Lumia 520 Internet Explorer 11 (IE 11).
I added additional code for showing tooltip:

```
$(".has_tooltip").tooltip();
if (/Lumia/.test(navigator.userAgent) && getInternetExplorerVersion() == 11)
        {
                $(".has_tooltip").click(function(){
                    $(this).tooltip("open");
                })
        }
```

So, in my case, `$(this).tooltip("open");` does the trick.

**in my mobile app tooltip is appearing when element is clicked.*