# Very slow on resize animation jQuery IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

This animation works ok in all browser but even if I am using stop() or check if animation is running IE8 is extremely slow on first load.  And if I remove resize it runs ok.

http://jsfiddle.net/uBWz8/7/

full screen view 
http://jsfiddle.net/uBWz8/7/embedded/result/

```
$(window).ready(function () {
    var findImg = $('.first').find('img');
    var firstImg = $("<img />").attr("src", findImg.attr('src') + "?" + new Date().getTime());

    $(firstImg).load(function () {

        var activeHeight = $('.slide').find('div').height();
        $('.first').stop().animate({
            opacity: 1,
            height: activeHeight
        }, 500);
    });

    $('.slide').each(function (index, element) {

        var h = $(this).find('div').height();

        $(this).css('height', h);

    });

});



$(window).resize(function () {

    var activeHeight = $('.slide').find('div').height();

    $('.first').stop().animate({
        height: activeHeight
    }, 500);

    $('.slide').each(function (index, element) {

        var h = $(this).find('div').height();

        $(this).css('height', h);

    });

});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does this help at all (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852751/window-resize-event-firing-in-internet-explorer)? Maybe the resize event is firing more often than you think so the animation keeps stoping, then restarting?

Comment: You may want to drop the animate part. resize triggers on absolutely any window change, so if you're dragging the resize box around you're sending resize furiously

Comment: GOD BLESS YOU! @drew_w. post tit as solution please so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the issue you have is related to the resize event firing more often than you would think. Basically whenever the animation starts it immediately fires the resize event, restarting the animation. This causes the animation to happen slowly or not at all!

For more information on the resize issue see here: [window.resize event firing in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852751/window-resize-event-firing-in-internet-explorer)

Best of luck!